# Page.php not showing changes in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

So, I am using Html5blank to recreate an html template in wordpress. I had no problems with the header and footer, they are both perfect. The problem I am running into is getting my page.php to show the changes I have made to it and it weirdly does not seem to be conforming to my css styles, either. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

ETA: I researched this site for quite a while and though there were a couple of questions that were somewhat similar, I didn't find anything that was my exact problem. I'm not sure why I got voted down but I suppose I should have mentioned that I did look around for this answer. Nobody seems to have this exact problem and if they have a similar one, their resolution didn't help me at all.

Here is the code for my page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="outermain">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <section id="maincontent" class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="main">

                        <section class="content">

                            <article class="post">
                                <div class="postimg">
                                    <div align="center">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="entry-date">
                                    <div class="postdate">02</div>
                                    <div class="posttime">September</div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="entry-text">
                                   <h2 class="posttitle">
<a href="single.html">Phasellus tempus mauris quis dui lobortis.</a></h2>

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                    <?php article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
<?php post_class(); ?>>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
                            </article>

    <?php endif; ?>


                        </section>

                    </div>
                </section>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="shadowbottom"></div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you need to display **page** content or **posts** Do you have any cache plugins installed. Have you flushed them and your browser cache. What debug info do you get

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close your WP Loop with:

```
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Roops, no content here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did as you say but it didn't help. I appreciate your time.